# Restore time capsule to virtual macOs

Tags: macos, vmware, time-capsule

I have an external HDD with an old time capsule on it. I don´t have a Mac to restore it to, but the time capsule contains a lot of old photos I´d like to extract.

So my question is; Can I spin up a virtual mac machine in eg. VmWare and restore my time capsule to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Migration is the easy bit. The tough bit is getting the VM to work on non-Apple hardware… which we can't help you with as it's off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I´ll continue my quest :)